Setting React state within handleSubmit callback using react-hook-form
I'm building some user inputs for a client-side application with react-hook-form.
The intention is to manage inputs via react-hook-form; store them as calculation parameters in useState and perform a number of expensive calculations via useMemo().
Users should be able to update an input. Then onBlur, react-hook-form is to validate the input and update an react useState object. If validation fails, the external state is not updated.
The following code paraphrases what I'm trying to achieve.
As the handleSubmit() function is async, i'm unable to set the state.
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

function App() {
  const [parameters, setParameters] = useState({
    variable: 0,
  });

  const [calculations, setCalculations] = useMemo(() => {
    return {}; // Expensive calculations
  }, [parameters]);

  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm({ mode: "onBlur" });

  return (
    <>
      {errors?.variable ? <p>{errors.variable.message}</p> : null}
      <label htmlFor="variable">Variable</label>
      <input
        {...register("variable", {
          onBlur: handleSubmit((data) => {
            setParameters((prev) => ({ ...prev, variable: data.variable }));
          }),
          required: { value: true, message: "Variable is required" },
        })}
        id="variable"
        type="text"
      />
    </>
  );
}



I've tried wrapping handleSubmit in async / await - however this doesn't yield anything as the handleSubmit method will only expose the result to the callback function.
useEffect on the react-hook-form watch() function; issue with this is you dont get the validation.
Creating my own synchronous methods to validate seem to defeat the purpose of using react-hook-form.


Curious, why do you need the state from react in this implementation?

Agreed with AyantunjiTimilehin. I don't see why you'd want to duplicate the form state into local state. This is a common React anti-pattern. Please [edit] to clarify what your question actually is and provide clearer details about what you are trying to accomplish.

@DrewReese Apologies - in trying to make the question clearer, I've obfuscated my actual intentions. Question has been edited - my intent is to perform expensive calculations via useMemo().

I see. So what is the actual question here then? What is the specific issue or problem you need help with? I understand you are trying to enqueue a React state update in the input's onBlur callback. What is the problem there?

The problem is that i'd like to use react-hook-forms handleSubmit() method - it verifies the inputs and only returns if successful. That method is async and takes a callback function as input. Setting the external react state via callback is whats causing problems.

And what exactly is the problem? I don't see any reason at all why you wouldn't be able to enqueue a React state update in the callback function. It feels like you still haven't clearly defined well enough what you are trying to do for a reader here to understand.
